# CMS links on frontend not converting ie href=[sitetree_link_id=xx]

Tags: silverstripe

An issue has been noticed on one of our old sites running 2.4 where when the user creates a link in the CMS content, selecting an existing page to link to, the link is not being converted to the actual URL on the front end and all links are coming through in the format of `<a href="[sitetree_link_id=12]">`

What would be causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: did you have a look at the plain html in tinymce? had some issues with links added to content pasted from other sources

Comment: The issue occurs when creating a new link from within the WYSIWYG rather than with pasted content.

Comment: href=[sitetree_link_id=xx] this is the way how silverstripe saves. so that is not the problem.
Are you by any chance overwriting the Content getter method or directly accessing $this->Content or similar in php?

Comment: have you got it working?

Comment: Unfortunately not. We are still at the stage where we are having to put hard links in

Comment: Fraser, to help with answering this question can you please get the following information: (1) the content from a relevant page in the CMS (click the HTML view in the WYSIWYG editor and copy the content from there), and (2) the content as it appears on the front-end site (go view source on the front-end site and copy the content from there)

Comment: Hi Sam, here is the link in the CMS <a href="[sitetree_link id=21]">Glenn</a> and here is how it appears in the front end: <a href="%5Bsitetree_link%20id=21%5D">Glenn</a>. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

The tag looks like it's being set incorrectly.  It should be `[sitetree_link id=12]`, not `[sitetree_link_id=12]`.

We later added support to the parser for `[sitetree_link,id=12]` so that links didn't need to contain spaces, but I can't recall if that's in 2.4 or only 3.0+.

Can you confirm that your WYSIWYG insertion is putting in that errant `_`?  If so, you might want to checkout the `handleaction_insert` function in `tiny_mce_imporvements.js` to confirm that it has a line like so:

```
case 'internal':
    href = '[sitetree_link id=' + this.elements.internal.value + ']';
```

If the inserted links don't actually have the errant `_` but they aren't being parsed, then try checking your sapphire/_config.php file for this:

```
ShortcodeParser::get('default')->register('sitetree_link', array('SiteTree', 'link_shortcode_handler'));
```

If your site makes changes to the `ShortcodeParser` at all you might have inadvertently turned off `sitetree_link` support.

If all of that looks in order, perhaps the ShortcodeParser isn't being called for some reason.  In `HTMLText::forTemplate()`, put a debug statement (I like `die("I got here!");`) to confirm that HTMLText::forTemplate() is actually getting called.  If it's not, you might need to manually call it in some pre-processing of your Content variable.  Instead of this:

```
$content = $this->Content;
```

Do this:

```
$content = $this->obj('Content')->forTemplate();
```

I hope that one of those answers help.  Either way, it would be great if you could post back, so we could isolate what caused this.  It might help us make the API easier to use in SilverStripe 3.1.

Comment: Very detailed answer, in my case the `$content = $this->Content` line was the culprit. +1